# Is it possible to add animation to my onboarding screen?

Tags: android-studio

I already have this onboarding page made up but I wanted to add some more interactivity to it and it consists of 4 pages and with each swipe I want to have a small animation to the logos.

[This what my onboarding looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0frT.png)

As you can see with the sample image, there's this image of a chatbot what I want to have for this is to animate the robot with the speech bubble popping up or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already did this one and I just put in a gif using this

[this](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable)